# Randomised Images is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, random

***Functionality:***
I am trying to set a randomised image page. Hence, when a user gets into a page, the table of images in the page are always randomised.

***What I have done:***

Firstly, I have created an array of image files as `var ImageArray=["","","",....]`. Secondly, I have created a randomised method as `var random_BrandIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);` and lastly, I created a for loop that will allow the image to populate the table created within the html body.

I have attached the code for your perusal:

```js
//Brand Array
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];
//To Set random Brand
var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
//Assign Variable to generate random Brands
var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];

$(function() {
  console.log(Brand);
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised
  for (i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++) {
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand[i]);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
  }
});
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
    <!--1st Row-->
    <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('3');">
    <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('4');">

    <!--2nd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
    <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
    <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
    <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

    <!--3rd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">

    <!--4th Row-->
    <img id="Brand_09" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">.....(more rows of images)...
  </div>
```

***Issue***

From the return console log, it is only return back only 1 brand when it should be returning a list of brands.
I would like to ask what have I done wrong and how am i able to append each return randomised image to the container within the div???

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code (`var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];`) so the Brand is a single string not an array.

```
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];
//To Set random Brand

$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
//Assign Variable to generate random Brands
var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, but at this point, there is a TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Furthermore, you might have missed out on Brand[i] @ `$('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);`. Am I correct to say so?

Comment: The error is in `for (i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++)` ; will this length be the length of the BrandNameArray or the count of images in your list? so that I can edit and correct the code.

Comment: @Luke I just edited the code setting the mentioned variable as count of the images please check it

Comment: ok, i just realised, that in that sense. the images appear could appear twice or three times. How is it possible to enable it to appear only once in each container??

Comment: If i edit the answer it won't match the question. if we are done till here. you can ask it in another question, or edit the question. or we can discuss it in chat.

Comment: I would like to discuss it in chat with you please. How do I open a chat with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107247/discussion-between-luke-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).